# Why aren't my nested attributes being destroyed along with the parent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Resume Model that has_many :skills, and my skills model that belongs_to :resume.

I am nesting the skills form inside the resume form and it's creating the record and relationship perfectly. But when I try to destroy the resume, the associated Skill is not being destroyed along with it.

Here are my models:

```
# Resume.rb

class Resume < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :skills

  belongs_to :user

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :skills, allow_destroy: true
end 


# Skill.rb

class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :resume
end
```

Here's the strong params in the resume_controller.rb

```
def resume_params
  params.require(:resume).permit(:user_id, :title, :summary, :job_title, skills_attributes [:skill_name, :_destroy])
end
```

As far as I can tell I am passing the _destroy key properly. I noticed some people had _destroy checkboxes in the form. I want the Skills to be deleted when I Destroy the entire resume. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

All you have specified is that you can destroy skills on a resume like with the checkboxes you mention seeing in some examples. If you want it to destroy all skills associated when a resume is destroyed you have adjust your `has_many` declaration.

```
has_many :skills, dependent: :destroy
```

Answer (score 2):

Add  `:dependent => :destroy`  in your `Resume` model like below:

```
class Resume < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :skills, :dependent => :destroy

  belongs_to :user

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :skills, allow_destroy: true
end
```

---

**`:dependent`**  Controls what happens to the associated objects when their owner is destroyed:

- `:destroy` causes all the associated objects to also be destroyed
- `:delete_all` causes all the associated objects to be deleted directly from the database (so callbacks will not execute)
- `:nullify` causes the foreign keys to be set to NULL. Callbacks are not executed.
- `:restrict_with_exception` causes an exception to be raised if there are any associated records
- `:restrict_with_error` causes an error to be added to the owner if there are any associated objects